# How can I enable "Add New Domain" button in GitLab Pages as an Administrator? Is there an existing configuration from Admin panel?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce, gitlab-pages

I want to add custom domains for GitLab Pages. I don't see any existing configuration from Gitlab admin settings panel.

I am seeing this message:
"Support for domains and certificates is disabled. Ask your system's administrator to enable it."

Have tried going through the documentation and googled some other links:

https://www.gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.md#dns-txt-record

All of them majorly focus on certificates edition and Domain configuration parts but none of them mention how to enable the "Add new Domain" button on GitLab Pages.

I have a single GitLab server and want my pages with custom domains to be served from the same server.

Comment: Did you follow the basic configuration guide and added the needed info in gitlab.rb ? https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/pages/index.html

Comment: @Zeitounator, Thank your for your response. I have added the related configuration as suggested in Gitlab documentation. I have added below fields in gitlab.rb and the Pages work well.
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
pages_external_url 'http://pages-internal.mygitlab.com'

The accessible URL for the deployed page is:
http://<namespace>.pages-internal.mygitlab.com/<project>

Now I want to access it with a shorter domain name like:
http://pro.mygitlab.com/<project>

How can I achieve this?